# What does this phrase mean: "Only Unreasonable Restraint of Trade Forbidden"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "Only Unreasonable Restraint of Trade Forbidden" refer to "Only Unreasonable Restraint of Trade **Is** Forbidden"?

Would you like to rewrite the phrase in more words so that I can understand it clearly?

> Standard Oil Company Must Dissolve in 6 Months; **Only Unreasonable Restraint of Trade Forbidden**
> And of Such Unreasonable Restraint the Supreme Court Finds the Standard Guilty

Source: [NYTimes Archive](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/learning/general/onthisday/big/0515.html)

Comment: This is headline-ese, not a real sentence. Words are omitted because it's a headline in a newspaper.

Comment: Thanks. But was my understanding correct there?

Comment: Yes, it is. Also the subject is omitted -- restraint of trade (is) forbidden (by whom).

Comment: "Whom" refers back to Standard Oil Company?

Comment: @NewPlanet - No, when FeliniusRex says "by whom" he means "by whoever is forbidding the action." Standard Oil is not doing the forbidding, the court is doing the forbidding.

Comment: @stangdon Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the case in question revolves around the sherman antitrust act.  This case is reversing the decision of a previous case by determining that the act is only violated by entities whose existence "unreasonably restrains" interstate commerce.  In the earlier supreme court case, they ruled that any company that restrains commerce could potentially violate the act.  (In other words, this case inserted the word "unreasonably" into the law).  So if a company, in this case standard oil, unreasonably restrains interstate commerce, they can be dissolved by the US government.

Tldr: the court overturned a previous ruling by adding that a company is only in violation of the sherman antitrust act if they "unreasonably"restrain interstate commerce.